# Laplace inverse for Taylor expansion

Tags: laplace-transform

By using infinite series find Laplace inverse for |1/(S^3+1)| .... I don't know what to do after using taylor expansion.. when I use it I got polynomial of $ S $ in the nominator which I can not deal with

Comment: If you use taylor expansion for this fraction it gives 1-$S^3$+$ S^6$ +....

Comment: Have you studied the power series of $1/(1+s^3)$ which I gave you?

Comment: See what I added.

Comment: By the way you can use maple or mathematics to give you the inverse Laplace of $1/(1+s^3)$ and compare with my answer.

Comment: I tried to get the first terms in this summation which were 1/(S^3) - 1/(S/6) +... they don't match with taylor expansion

Comment: If you are doing your calculations correct then they should match. Just take your time and do not rush I already gave you a full answer to your problem!

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you advance.

> $$ \frac{1}{1+s^3} = \frac{1}{s^3(1+\frac{1}{s^3})} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{s^{3k+3}}$$

Apply inverse Laplace you get

$$  \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k\, x^{3 k+2}}{\Gamma(3k+3)}. $$

Now you sum the above series.

**Added:** Here is the summation of the series using CAS

$$ \frac{1}{3}\,{{\rm e}^{1/2\,x}}\sin \left( 1/2\,\sqrt {3}x \right) \sqrt {3}-1
/3\,{{\rm e}^{1/2\,x}}\cos \left( 1/2\,\sqrt {3}x \right) +1/3\,{
{\rm e}^{-x}}
 .$$

Comment: I am not convinced with summation form cause when k equals zero it should give out one which don't happen with this form

Comment: What's wrong with the case $k=0$? Do you know what's the inverse Laplace of $1/s^{m}$?

Comment: If you use taylor expansion for this fraction it gives 1-$S^3$+$ S^6$ +....

Answer (score 0):

This is far easier using the definition of the inverse transform, i.e.,

$$\frac1{i 2 \pi} \int_{c-i \infty}^{c+i \infty} ds \frac{e^{s t}}{s^3+1} $$

If you know complex analysis, then you know that this integral is simply the sum of the residues of the poles of the integrand.  The poles are at $s=e^{i \pi/3}$, $s=e^{i \pi}$, and $s=e^{i 5 \pi/3} = e^{-i \pi/3}$.  The sum of the residues is then

$$\frac{e^{e^{i \pi/3} t}}{3 e^{i 2 \pi/3}} + \frac{e^{e^{-i \pi/3} t}}{3 e^{-i 2 \pi/3}} + \frac13 e^{-t} = \frac{1}{3} e^{t/2} \left [\sqrt{3} \sin{\left (\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} t \right )}-\cos{\left (\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} t \right )} \right ]+\frac13 e^{-t}$$